# Jquery Resizable Issue in firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on Jquery Resizable and it works fine without any css changes. But, if I change the div `display` to `table-cell` the resizable doesn't work in IE and Firefox. I have to use table-cell because of some layout issues. Do you have any solutions for the problem?

I have link to the fiddle source
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGL9L/3/)

Thanks in advance